# Visualforce relatedList on Account's ServiceContracts returns unrelated Service Contracts

Tags: visualforce, related-list

Scenario - Custom VF page that overrides Account View button. Simplified version below:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account" >

  <apex:pageMessages id="pageMsgs" showDetail="true"/>
  <apex:detail inlineEdit="true" relatedList="false" showChatter="true" subject="{!Account.id}"/>   
  <apex:relatedList list="Contacts"/>
  <apex:relatedList list="Cases"/>
  <apex:relatedList list="ServiceContracts" subject="{!Account.id}"/>

</apex:page>
```

- The `ServiceContracts` related list **always returns all Service Contracts in the database**, not just the ones associated to the specific account
- The other related lists work as expected, only Cases and Contacts for the account in question
- I tried with and without the `subject` attribute - same results
- I tried at VF page V27 and V29; same result

I could obviously build a controller extension and create a custom related list for `ServiceContracts` but I'm a bit gobsmacked that this fundamental `relatedlist` doesn't return just the Service Contracts for the account in question.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Front line SFDC dev support reproduced and has referred to backline developer support; case# 09931190

Comment: Back line SFDC support has now reproduced this.

Comment: Back line SFDC support has reproduced in their own orgs and sent to R&D

Comment: Identified as a bug; now a known issue - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T2EgAAK